# Geolocation to imput field and form submition (google script)

Tags: javascript, google-apps

Hi i have this link to get the current user position by GPS. Its part of a form script i made getting diferent codes from different places.

when pressing the button it shows a paragraph with coordinates.

```
<button onclick="getLocation()">Obtener coordenadas de GPS del movil</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
} else { 
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
  }
}

function showPosition(position) {
x.innerHTML = position.coords.latitude + "," + position.coords.longitude;
}

</script>
```

But i want to populate this field in the form:

```
<div id="formDiv">
<!-- Form div will be hidden after form submission -->
<form id="myForm">
<br/>
Ubicacion: <input name="ubicacion" type="text" size="64" /><br/>
```

anyone knows if its posible? tryed several things, but none working, till i dont know much of javascript.

this is the form: [site](https://sites.google.com/site/gtbicival/)

At pressing "obtener coordenadas del GPS" it should fill the "Ubicacion" imput field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! i should have used another formula: `.value` not `.innerHTML`

```
 <button onclick="getLocation()">Obtener coordenadas de GPS del movil</button><br/>
<script>
 function getLocation() {
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
} else { 
    document.getElementById("ub").value = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
       }
}
function showPosition(position) {
document.getElementById("ub").value = 
     position.coords.latitude + "," +   position.coords.longitude;
}
</script>
```

seems that also using `var x =`  doesnt work

```
 Ubicacion: <input name="ubicacion" type="text" size="64" /><br/>
```